# How to delete folder with strange name?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, delete

I don't know how I've done this but I've created somehow a folder named "-p".
Now I'm trying to delete it but my buntu is thinking I'm passing -p as a paremeter.

What can I do?

Ubuntu Server 15.

Comment: Agree the duplicate flag. Sorry. The S.E. "Question Title Suggestion Machine" does not show me the dup because I don't use any of its terms (`delete folder strange` versus `commands with dash parameter`).

Comment: No need to be sorry - the next person using the same search terms as you will find your post AND the one it links to, so your question makes the site better :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `--` to tell `rm` (and many other commands including many shell built-ins) not to interpret any further input as command parameters, so that `-p` can be interpreted correctly as an argument instead of an "unrecognised option"

```
rm -- -p
```

(This is also a good safety measure when globbing. You might have accidentally created a file called `-rf`...)

Comment: "You can use `--` to tell bash not to interpret any further input as command parameters" — Isn't it actually telling `rm` not to interpret any further parameters as options?

Comment: `--` is interpreted by `rm`, not `bash`. And while there is a recommendation in the SUS for tools to accept this special separator, there is no requirement to do so, and not all of them do. `dd` is well known for having a radically different syntax from what we now consider to be "standard" syntax (i.e. GNU `getoptlong`), for example.

Comment: I'll try this ASAP.

Comment: @Zanna thanks for the answer but as this is a duplicate question I'll flag to delete.

Comment: @MagnoC there's no need to delete - it's still a useful question/signpost. we don't delete dupes unless they are bad :)

Answer (score 6):

the proper way in this case is :

```
rm ./-p
```

`--` may work with some commands, and fail with others. it is not bash that interprets it, but each command separately (and some may not recognise `--` as the end of options) (especially true if you ever use non gnu commands... for example if you work on some other OSs).

Taking the habit of saying `./somefileorglob` instead of just `somefileorglob` is a good habit, in general.

Comment: Yes a very good habit. Plus you need `./` to run a script in the current directory too. Whereas `-- script-name` doesn't work. Plus `--` is a fringe thing hard to remember.

Comment: As I can remember ( I'm at work now and the problem is at my home machine) I've already tried this and not worked. Including `rm -rf "./-p"`(double quoted)

Comment: @MagnoC: this is strange... maybe there are additionnal ("invisible") characters in that name? Try in that case first to :  `ls -l ./*-*p* | cat -ve` may help in most cases:  `-v` will make cat make some characters visible (^M, for example) and combined with `e` it will also mark the end of each lines with "$", which helps when the line has trailing spaces or tabs. This can help determine the name. or use "od" on the output. You can also use Tab completion:  `ls -ld ./-` and press TAB to let bash complete the rest (or show a selection if there are several candidates). CAREFUL: Tab, not SPACE